# Galaxy Generation Algorithm

Tags: c#, procedural-generation

I'm trying to generate a set of points (represented by a `Vector` struct) that roughly models a spiral galaxy.

The C# code I've been playing with is below; but I can only seem to get it to generate a single 'arm' of the galaxy.

```
    public Vector3[] GenerateArm(int numOfStars, int numOfArms, float rotation)
    {
        Vector3[] result = new Vector3[numOfStars];
        Random r = new Random();

        float fArmAngle = (float)((360 / numOfArms) % 360);
        float fAngularSpread = 180 / (numOfArms * 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfStars; i++)
        {

            float fR = (float)r.NextDouble() * 64.0f;
            float fQ = ((float)r.NextDouble() * fAngularSpread) * 1;
            float fK = 1;

            float fA = ((float)r.NextDouble() % numOfArms) * fArmAngle;


            float fX = fR * (float)Math.Cos((MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(fA + fR * fK + fQ)));
            float fY = fR * (float)Math.Sin((MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(fA + fR * fK + fQ)));

            float resultX = (float)(fX * Math.Cos(rotation) - fY * Math.Sin(rotation));
            float resultY = (float)(fY * Math.Cos(rotation) - fX * Math.Sin(rotation));

            result[i] = new Vector3(resultX, resultY, 1.0f);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you need a second loop based on the numOfArms and offseting the arm angle by the angular distance between the arms.  Then change your inner iteration loop to be numOfStars / numOfArms.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on gamedev?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348321/mathematical-question-procedural-generation-of-a-galaxy

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve the problem, but what is the point of the 'degrees to radians' function? Why not just generate your angles in radians in the first place?

Comment: Fair comment.  I'll try that.

Comment: The other stackoverflow question talks about generating a galaxy using random seeded, however doesn't touch on placement of stars based upon a spiral galaxy.  Thanks for the link though

Comment: What's the point of %360? It's not like your going to have `numOfArms < 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would abstract that function out into a `createArm` function.

Then you can store each arm as its own galaxy (temporarily).

So if you want 2 arms, do 2 galaxies of 5000. Then, rotate one of them 0 degrees around the origin (so doesn't move) and the other 180 degrees around the origin.

With this you can do an arbitrary number of arms by using different rotation amounts. You could even add some "naturalization" to it by making the rotation distance more random, like with a range instead of straight (360 / n). For example, 5 arms would be 0, 72, 144, 216, 288. But with some randomization you could make it 0, 70, 146, 225, 301.

Edit:

Some quick google-fu tells me ([source](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/2drota.htm))

```
q = initial angle, f  = angle of rotation.

x = r cos q
y = r sin q

x' = r cos ( q + f ) = r cos q cos f - r sin q sin f
y' = r sin ( q + w ) = r sin q cos f + r cos q sin f

hence:
x' = x cos f - y sin f
y' = y cos f + x sin f
```

Comment: Any ideas how I might go about changing the algorithm to 'rotate' all the values around 0.0?

I could do it with a rotation matrix on each point, but it would be better to be able to pass in an 'rotation offset' value into the createArm function, and have the points rotated on generation.

Comment: are there any spiral galaxies with a number of arms other than two?  i don't think it happens unless perhaps it's a transient feature due to disruption in some way (merger / collision).

Comment: @Chris I added some formulas shameless ripped from siggraph.

Comment: @andrew the Milky Way has 2 primary arms, and 4 smaller ones.

Comment: really?  huh.  how embarassing.  i was once an astronomer...!

Comment: I updated the function above to include the rotation, but it doesn't seem to be rotating correctly... any ideas?

Comment: Your y should be `+` not `-`. Review the equations carefully.

Comment: Damn that cut + paste coding!

Comment: @Chris too true. Too too true. Whenever I'm copying and pasting, I know one of two thing is happening: I'm about to forget to change a subtle difference between the copied code and the pasted code, or I'm duplicating code that really should be refactored into a function. Copy/paste is a prototype programmer's best friend, and a maintenance programmer's nightmare!

Answer (score 5):

Check this. It's a simulation of galaxy using density wave theory. Code is available.
http://beltoforion.de/galaxy/galaxy_en.html

Comment: the link is dead, but for all of those that still want to read it use the following link https://web.archive.org/web/20140119101505/http://beltoforion.de/galaxy/galaxy_en.html

Comment: The reports of the links death are greatly exaggerated ;)
And this article is great. Thanks!

Comment: To me the link also looks very alive and the article is awesome.
Here the two github repos from the link for your convenience :)
https://github.com/beltoforion/Galaxy-Renderer (C++)
https://github.com/beltoforion/Galaxy-Renderer-Typescript

Answer (score 5):

I liked this idea so much i had to play around with it on my own and here is my result.
Note that i used PointF instead of Vector3, but you should be able to search and replace and add `, 0)` in a few places.

```
PointF[] points;

private void Render(Graphics g, int width, int height)
{
    using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(20, 150, 200, 255)))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Black);
        foreach (PointF point in points)
        {
            Point screenPoint = new Point((int)(point.X * (float)width), (int)(point.Y * (float)height));
            screenPoint.Offset(new Point(-2, -2));
            g.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(screenPoint, new Size(4, 4)));
        }
        g.Flush();
    }
}

public PointF[] GenerateGalaxy(int numOfStars, int numOfArms, float spin, double armSpread, double starsAtCenterRatio)
{
    List<PointF> result = new List<PointF>(numOfStars);
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfArms; i++)
    {
        result.AddRange(GenerateArm(numOfStars / numOfArms, (float)i / (float)numOfArms, spin, armSpread, starsAtCenterRatio));
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}

public PointF[] GenerateArm(int numOfStars, float rotation, float spin, double armSpread, double starsAtCenterRatio)
{
    PointF[] result = new PointF[numOfStars];
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfStars; i++)
    {
        double part = (double)i / (double)numOfStars;
        part = Math.Pow(part, starsAtCenterRatio);

        float distanceFromCenter = (float)part;
        double position = (part * spin + rotation) * Math.PI * 2;

        double xFluctuation = (Pow3Constrained(r.NextDouble()) - Pow3Constrained(r.NextDouble())) * armSpread;
        double yFluctuation = (Pow3Constrained(r.NextDouble()) - Pow3Constrained(r.NextDouble())) * armSpread;

        float resultX = (float)Math.Cos(position) * distanceFromCenter / 2 + 0.5f + (float)xFluctuation;
        float resultY = (float)Math.Sin(position) * distanceFromCenter / 2 + 0.5f + (float)yFluctuation;

        result[i] = new PointF(resultX, resultY);
    }

    return result;
}

public static double Pow3Constrained(double x)
{
    double value = Math.Pow(x - 0.5, 3) * 4 + 0.5d;
    return Math.Max(Math.Min(1, value), 0);
}
```

Example:

```
points = GenerateGalaxy(80000, 2, 3f, 0.1d, 3);
```

Result: 
[image: Galaxy]